# Takes long time to load the login page from Apache web server

Tags: apache-2.2

We have an `Apache` web server 2.2.22 installed in Ubuntu 12.04.4. The site uses `PHP` pages and `MySQL` as database in a dedicated DB server.

Once in a while, we face slowness connecting our site and see that the site page loading time is increased. It takes `10 seconds to 30 seconds` to display the login page. This happens for a few minutes then the website page loading is fast for an hour or two and then the issue happens again like this all day. The server is hosted by a third party vendor and confirmed with their support that there is no issue with the data center network.

The CPU & Memory resources are not utilized much and the disk I/O seems normal. I searched internet for the similar issue and checked a few Apache settings like `Hostnamelookup Off` and `MaxRequestPerChild` setting. All look fine.

Will there be anything I need to check at the Apache settings.? This issue started recently. There was no configuration change but the website loads slow. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: might be related to database queries taking some time, but it is hard to say, you could use something like New Relic or other tracing tools to understand on what is going on and fix it.

Comment: Enable acces logs `CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined`. That provide details about each request, and also check the query logs of mysql. A monitoring system like zabbix might give you a complete overview. You can also use a tool like fiddler on a client to do a end to end trace to exactly see where the delay is.

Comment: Fiddler is a popular web debugging proxy tool that can intercept and inspect web traffic, including HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely not a configuration issue in apache, php, or mysql, but instead some other activity on the server causing the periodic slowness. Check for other processes running in that window where the site is slow. Given the environment you mentioned, I bet something is running on that server periodically like a cron job doing a backup or someone running AWStats with way too much log retention.

Comment: There is no cron job or anyother process that runs in the server. I used google chrome's `developer mode` to see where the page loading takes time. I see few `css` scripts take few seconds to load. The `connection setup` is fast, `DNS lookup, Inital connection, SSL` takes only few milli seconds, but at the `Request/Response` side `waiting for TTFB` takes more time `(15s,18s,23s..)`. Will there be any issue with loading the scripts? or something else with the server?

Comment: The .htaccess file was huge and I removed few entries that are made for blocking web robots and made entries in robots.txt. After that the site's response seems better. I'm just monitoring the site speed for a few days.

Answer (score -1):

> All look fine

Why are you telling us about it then?

Once you've made some in roads in analyzing the problem, if you don't have a solution come back here with details of what you tried, what you found, what your configs actually are and what hardware this is running on.

The FIRST place you should be looking is in the web developer tools when the problem manifests. A DNS issue would explain a one-off slowness, but not one that persists for several requests.

Add timing to your webserver logs (%D not %T) and reconcile slow requests at the browser with those on the log server. Maybe the problem is not on the webserver.

You didn't even tell us what OS this is running on. Assuming this is Linux/BSD, then setup sar (if its not already running) and check the data its logging at slow times compared with "normal".

Comment: An 8 year old question? seriously?

Comment: Blame serverfault. But other people are going to find this when looking to diagnose why their server is slow today.